# Sitecore WFFM - Missing field properties of custom field

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, custom-fields, web-forms-for-marketers

I've created a new `DatePicker` field by following all steps of *Creating DatePicker Field Type* section of [this guideline](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/web%20forms%20for%20marketers%20v2_3%20reference-usletter.pdf).

In the form designer I see `The field has no properties` text for the field. Although there are `[VisualProperty]` attributes for some properties in the code, the properties are not being shown in the form designer window.

I need to create my own fields with some properties.

Does somebody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with custom fields, I've found it easier to pick an existing field and extend it rather than create one from scratch. Depending on what functionality you are looking for, you could pick the existing field type which is closest to what you need.

It sounds like your properties might not be initialized. I can't really tell you anything more useful without looking at your code.

When I had to do something like this, I used [WFFM Custom Field Type made easy](http://divamatrix.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/wffm-custom-field-type-made-easy/) article as a reference, and mainly Reflector to look at how other field types were implemented by Sitecore. You can also read [my blog post here](http://elenazlateva.blogspot.com/2012/09/custom-field-type-for-sitecore-web.html).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In the created custom Field Type item find the checkbox field "Required" (Under Behaviour field section)

[image]

You are good to go now, You will find the required checkbox enabled for your custom field in form designer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this when not inheriting from one of the existing fields and instead inheriting from these base field types. I resolved this by putting any VisualProperties right near the top of my class, just after any other properties like so:

```html
[ValidationProperty("Value")]
MyCustomField : ValidateUserControl, IHasTitle 

protected Panel ControlContainer;
protected TextBox Field1;
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label Help;

[Localize, VisualCategory("Appearance"), VisualFieldType(typeof(EditField)), VisualProperty("Help Text:", 101)]
public string HelpText
{
  get
    {
      return this.Help.Text;
    }
  set
    {
      this.Help.Text = value;
    }
 }
```

For some reason when adding these further down in my code the custom Property fields didn't show up. Hope this helps.